# Can/should multiple application contexts share a common microservice in a single namespace?

Tags: microservices, namespace, kubernetes

My current employer has a single namespace into which all microservices for all projects are deployed.

Projects A, B and C all use microservice x in this common namespace:

[image]

Rather than each design and implement their own microservice that performs the same behaviour (for example for some common domain object CRUD operations against a database), Projects A, B and C all use and claim shared-ownership of a common implementation - microservice x - and service it in accordance with their project requirements.

Projects are upsetting the shared ecosystem for each other when deploying revised versions of x (downtime, breaking changes).

I am unclear if this is an example of what Kubernetes best practices considers to be an example of an "[overcrowded namespace](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/08/kubernetes-namespaces-use-cases-insights/)" anti-pattern - I am thrown by the fact that each project utilises a common microservice and I thought one of the points of microservices was to expose common things in a kind of public way like this?

Is it appropriate for this "public exposure" to manifest as a single service instance in a common namespace?

Or should the namespaces split apart and they all have their own deployment of microservice x like this?

[image]